# How to disable dragging to the left and right in Open Layers 3

Tags: javascript, dictionary, drag, openlayers-3

I have a map but i want disable the right and left drag map.

```
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [layerTile],
    target: 'map',
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({ dragPan: false}),
    view: view
  });
```

This code remove all drag movement but I just want remove the right and left movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take alook at this question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164310/pan-panel-for-ol3). There is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/hLzm22um/) in the answer. I think you can set

```
dragPan: false;
```

and use the pan controls like the one in the fiddle